# How to add audio in background like google santa tracker

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, html5-audio

I am trying to add background audios like https://santatracker.google.com which works even in mobile browsers and when we change our tab it gets paused and when we go again on the tab audio gets resumed. I tried playing audio using xhr request but pausing it and replaying it is not possible.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, Santatracker uses XHR requests to get audio in ogg format and *Page Activity API*.

More useful details here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API
- http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/ (example)

Comment: I haven't asked how to implement page activity api i am asking that how to pause and play the audio's